# Why is sysctlbyname not defined if I include it in a block as a dispatch_once arg?

Tags: macos

I import:

```
#import <sys/types.h>
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
```

When I use the function, `sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);` outside `dispatch_once`, the compiler finds its definition in . When I use it inside the block inside the second argument to `dispatch_once`, I get this error:

```
No matching function for call to 'sysctlbyname'
```

Here's the full code:

```
#import <sys/types.h>
#import <sys/sysctl.h>

NSString *GetMachineName(void) {
  static NSString *machine = nil;

  if (nil == machine) {
    size_t size;

    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); // DEFINED IN SYSCTL.H


    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
      // Set 'oldp' parameter to NULL to get the size of the data
      // returned so we can allocate appropriate amount of space
      sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); // DEFINED IN SYSCTL.H

      // Allocate the space to store name
      char *name = (char *)malloc(size);

      // Get the platform name
      sysctlbyname("hw.machine", name, &size, NULL, 0);

      // Place name into a string
      machine = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

      // Done with this
      free(name);
    });

    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return IPHONE_1G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return IPHONE_3G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) return IPHONE_3GS_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) return IPHONE_4G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]) return IPOD_1G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]) return IPOD_2G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"]) return IPOD_3G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]) return IPAD_1G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"]) return IPAD_2G_PLATFORM;
    if ([machine isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [machine isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) return SIMULATOR_PLATFORM;
    return NULL;
  }

  return machine;
}
```

Comment: Can't duplicate, could you show your code?

Comment: Still can't duplicate in XCode 4.5. The only related warning is that `size` is closed to a `const size_t`, so you should move that declaration inside the block. Other than that, compiles without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To fix, I needed to put the declaration of `size` inside the block, because as it was, the argument wasn't decorated with `__block`, so it compiles to a `const`, mismatching the argument list of `sysctlbyname`. Because of function overloading, the compiler found that the function didn't exist.

TLDR: The compiler thought the function I was using was

```
int sysctlbyname(const char *, void *, const size_t*, void *, size_t);
```

rather than

```
int sysctlbyname(const char *, void *, *size_t, void *, size_t);
```